# Automation using python docx to update Header and Footer update

Tags: python

Please help in resolving the below error while executing the following piece of code. 
The piece of code gets text input from GUI to update the  header and footer.

The code is shown below.

```
doc = docx.Document(self.name.get())
header = doc.sections[0].header
footer = doc.sections[0].footer
header.is_linked_to_previous = True
header.add_paragraph(text= str(self.header1.get()))
footer.is_linked_to_previous = True
footer.add_paragraph(text= str(self.footer1.get()))
doc.save("docss.docx")
```

The error details:

```
AttributeError: 'Section' object has no attribute 'header'
```

System configuration:

```
Windows 10
MSWORD 2013
Python version: 3.7 64 bit
```

Im trying to install Python docX Version is 0.8.10 but its giving error:

```
"Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement python-docx (from versions: )
    No matching distribution found for python-docx"
```